# Подкрашивание нескольких ячеек pandas и вывод результата в excel

Tags: python, pandas

Только начинаю изучать pandas, и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Создал `dataframe`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sector': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
    '1800 NewSite': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    'Add 1800':  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
    'newsite': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
    '1800 Entrance': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
    'ТР':[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]})
```

Необходимо подкрасить ячейки по условиям и вывести результат в excel.
Условия для подкрашивания:

- если `1800 NewSite` != `newsite` и `newsite` не пустое значение и `ТР` != 1 - цвет красный
- если `1800 NewSite` != `newsite` и `newsite` не пустое значение и `ТР` == 1 - цвет желтый
- если `1800 Entrance` != `Add 1800` и `Add 1800` не пустое значение и `ТР` != 1 - цвет красный
- если `1800 Entrance` != `Add 1800` и `Add 1800` не пустое значение и `ТР` == 1 - цвет желтый

Получилось подкрасить только одну из ячеек. Подскажите пожалуйста, как подкрашивать несколько ячеек.

Код для подкрашивания ячеек:

```py
def highlight(df, cols2highlight):
    ret = pd.DataFrame('', index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
    ret.loc[
        (df['1800 NewSite'] != df['newsite']) & (df['newsite'].notnull()) | ((df['1800 NewSite'] > 0) &
                                                                                (df['newsite'].isnull())),
        cols2highlight] = 'background-color: red'
    ret.loc[
        ((df['1800 NewSite'] != df['newsite']) & (df['newsite'].notnull()) | ((df['1800 NewSite'] > 0) &
                                                                                (df['newsite'].isnull())))
        & (df['ТР'] == 1),
        cols2highlight] = 'background-color: yellow'
    return ret
    df2 = df.style.apply(highlight, cols2highlight='newsite', axis=None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Условия в вашем коде не соответствуют условиям в тексте вопроса. Также их желательно структурировать, чтобы не запутаться, и чтобы код был лаконичнее. Комментарии в коде.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sector': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
                   '1800 NewSite': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                   'Add 1800': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                   'newsite': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                   '1800 Entrance': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                   'ТР': [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]})


def highlight(df):
    ret = pd.DataFrame(None, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
    # задаем основные правила закраски в виде словаря, где ключ - наименование столбца, который нужно красить, а значение - булев массив,
    # какие ячейки красить (пока без конкретного цвета)
    masks = {'newsite': df['1800 NewSite'] != df['newsite'] & df['newsite'].notnull(),
             '1800 Entrance': df['1800 Entrance'] != df['Add 1800'] & df['Add 1800'].notnull()}
    red, yellow = df['ТР'].ne(1), df['ТР'].eq(1)  # делаем булевы массивы для красного и желтого цветов 
    # перебираем словарь с правилами закраски
    for column, mask in masks.items():
        ret.loc[mask & red, column] = 'background-color: red'  # дополняем булев массив (маску) условием закраски в красный и красим
        ret.loc[mask & yellow, column] = 'background-color: yellow'  # дополняем булев массив (маску) условием закраски в желтый и красим

    return ret


df2 = df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
df2.to_excel('style.xlsx')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Алексей, спасибо большое за подсказку. Немного не так получилось... Должна выполняться проверка равенства 1800 NewSite - newsite с условием по ТР, и закрашиваться колонка newsite. Далее идёт проверка Add 1800 и 1800 Entrance с условием по ТР - закрашивается колонка 1800 entrance. Т.е., закрашивание колонок не должно быть связано, newsite и 1800 entrance красятся по своим условиям независимо друг от друга. Мой код по функции highlight не соответствует условию, но я её привел просто чтоб показать, что у меня только одна колонка закрашенной получается. А вот как перейти к закраске второй колонки?

Comment: 1. Условия очень желательно писать в вопросе как можно точнее и понятнее, 2. Переделал решение.